# Laplace approximation for two gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to estimate p(x) knowing p(z) and p(x|z).
Assume that we have: **z ~ normal gaussian distribution**, and **x = g(z) + noise**.

Then we have the following distributions:

[p(z)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWL0S.png)

[p(x|z)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0X4Q.png)

[p(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d49GJ.png)

I am not sure how to approximate such an integral.. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $g$ here?

Comment: g is some invertible function which takes norm gaussian distribution as an input